# Authentication with Clerk in Next.js redirects to /sign-in page after signing in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, vercel, clerk

I've been using clerk for authentication but after signing in , it is redirecting to /sign-in page after signing in even though env is NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/

Checked and confirmed the correctness of the environment variable.
Verified Clerk configuration in the Next.js application.
Examined the code for explicit redirects or unintended navigation.
Checked Clerk Dashboard settings.
Ensured that Clerk and related dependencies are up to date.

Comment: I have the same issue with Clerk / NextJs on Vercel.

User attempts to sign-up or sign-in using the Clerk provided auth components, but the webpage just hangs on the redirect.

Everything is configured as per the Clerk documentation. No customisation. This issue occurs intermittently which is very frustrating as it's hard to replicate.

So we're asking users of our platform to perform a hard refresh and try again.

Windows: CTRL + SHIFT + R Mac: CMD + SHIFT + R